# Google sheets importHTML removes zero and treats commas as decimal

Tags: google-sheets, html-table

I'm trying to import a table where the commas are the 1000 separator, 
example: 32,100 is 32100 but it is treating it as 32.1 instead.

This is a similar table (first one / top left):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_world

imgur for screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qy7j3.jpg

I want it to say:

```
Year    million
1500    458
1600    580
1700    682
1750    791
1800    978
1850    1262
1900    1650
1950    2521
1999    5978
2008    6707
2011    7000
2015    7350
2018    7600
2020    7750
```

But it comes out as:

```
Year    million
1500    458
1600    580
1700    682
1750    791
1800    978
1850    1,262
1900    1,65
1950    2,521
1999    5,978
2008    6,707
2011    7
2015    7,35
2018    7,6
2020    7,75
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_world"; "table"; 1)
```

I have also tried using this function:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_world"; "//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/table[1]/tbody")
```

But that shows as this witch is extremely hard to understand since it looks like this and still removes the zeros:

```
World Population[1][2]  Yearmillion 1500458 1600580 1700682 1750791 1800978 18501,262   19001,65    19502,521   19995,978   20086,707   20117   20157,35    20187,6 20207,75
```

Other things i have tried is:
forsing it to always print out three decimals, that wont work since it adds more numbers to the end of all numbers.

Comment: what is your `Spreadsheet Settings` - `File > Spreadsheet Settings`

Comment: @BHAWANISINGH Language code is Swedish, changing it to USA fixed it, but is there any way to make it work with my default language? is it any way i can import the data as text instead of numbers? would be nice since i have to redo some things if i change the language.

Comment: Luddeb123, please check if the following works `=arrayformula(iferror(value(IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_world"; "table"; 1));IMPORTHTML("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_world"; "table"; 1)))`

Comment: @BHAWANISINGH Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. It shows the same as it did previously.

Comment: I feel _changing locale is the only way_ here, since the table is converted to range of values (which considers spreadsheet locale) by `importrange` first, and we only get the processed range of values at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The main & easiest possible solution that you have is to change your Spreadsheet's `locale` setting to one that uses the `,` as mile separator.

As an alternative, if changing this setting is really not a possibility, you could create a script that uses [`URLFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) to retrieve the page's contents and parses the values, taking into considerations the usage of `,` as mile separator.